# Are there poly time algorithms to determine if a graph is almost bipartite?

Tags: ds.algorithms, graph-theory

Given an undirected graph G, we can say that G is almost bipartite if deleting k edges (or vertices) would make it bipartite.

Are there poly time algorithms to determine if a graph is exactly or approximately almost bipartite?

Comment: What do you mean by "approximately almost bipartite"? ​ ​

Comment: It's np-hard for general $k$ because it's basically the max cut problem. I don't think this is research-level

Comment: @RickyDemer I meant that  the output could be a 1 + eps approximation of the number of edges or vertices needed to make the graph bipartite for example. I would allow some probability is of error too.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The vertex version is called "odd cycle transversal"; it's NP-complete but fixed-parameter tractable. See:

Yannakakis, Mihalis (1978), "Node-and edge-deletion NP-complete problems", Proceedings of the 10th ACM Symposium on Theory of Computing (STOC '78), pp. 253–264, [doi:10.1145/800133.804355](http://doi.org/10.1145/800133.804355).

Reed, Bruce; Smith, Kaleigh; Vetta, Adrian (2004), "Finding odd cycle transversals", Operations Research Letters, 32 (4): 299–301, doi:[10.1016/j.orl.2003.10.009](http://doi.org/10.1016/j.orl.2003.10.009).

Hüffner, Falk (2005), "Algorithm engineering for optimal graph bipartization", Experimental and Efficient Algorithms: 240–252, [doi:10.1007/11427186_22](http://doi.org/10.1007/11427186_22).

The edge version has been called "edge bipartization"; it's also NP-complete but fixed-parameter tractable. See:

Guo, Jiong; Gramm, Jens; Hüffner, Falk; Niedermeier, Rolf; Wernicke, Sebastian (2006), "Compression-based fixed-parameter algorithms for feedback vertex set and edge bipartization", *JCSS* 72 (8): 1386–1396, [doi:10.1016/j.jcss.2006.02.001](http://doi.org/10.1016/j.jcss.2006.02.001).

(added following daniello's comment):

Odd cycle transversal has an $O(\sqrt{\log n})$ approximation algorithm, but (assuming the Unique Games Conjecture) no constant-factor approximation; see (references copied from "On Polynomial Kernels for Structural Parameterizations of Odd Cycle Transversal" by Jansen and Kratsch):

Agarwal, Amit, Charikar, Moses, Makarychev, Konstantin, Makarychev, Yury, $O(\sqrt{\log n})$ approximation algorithms for Min UnCut, Min 2CNF deletion, and directed cut problems, STOC'05, pp. 573–581.

Khot, S., On the power of unique 2-prover 1-round games, STOC '02, pp. 767–775.

Wernicke, S., On the algorithmic tractability of single nucleotide polymorphism (SNP) analysis and related problems. Master’s thesis, Wilhelm-Schickard-Institut für Informatik, U. Tübingen (2003)

Comment: I seem to remember the problem is also unique games hard to approximate within any constant factor, but don't remember the reference

Comment: Thank you for this great answer. Do the hardness results there can be no poly time property testing algorithm even if we allow approximation and randomness?

Comment: Does the largest eigenvalue of the Laplacian give some indication of bipartiteness?

Comment: A similar, although much simpler (it is polynomial), question is raised here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3927366/check-whether-a-given-graph-is-bipartite-except-for-one-edge/ -- any idea?

Comment: I see  Agarwal, Amit, Charikar, Moses, Makarychev, Konstantin, Makarychev, Yury, O(logn−−−−√) approximation algorithms for Min UnCut, Min 2CNF deletion, and directed cut problems, STOC'05, pp. 573–581.  
is doing graph bipartization (edge version)  from min uncut does the vertex version also follow?